# Printing selected pages in Excel Worksheet with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a worksheet in Excel with several pages. I want to print selected pages, e.G. Page 1, Page 3, Page 4 and Page 6. Can I do this in a singel print job?

In know i can print the pages with the commands:
`ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=3, Copies:=3, Collate:=True
ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=4, Collate:=True
ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=6, Copies:=6, Collate:=True`

But this way, i create a lot of print jobs. Therefore i look like something like
PrintOut(Page1, Page 3, Page 4, ....)

---

More Information about my Problem:
There are a delivery notes in my Worksheets: [Excel delivery notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p6pn.png)
Some of them dont have entries in the C-column. (for example Page 2). I wrote a Makro which iterates over the pagebreakes and check the C-column on every page:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LieferscheineDrucken()
Dim HPB As HPageBreak
Dim breakAdress As Integer
Dim pageNumber As Integer
Dim productNumber As Integer
Dim printCondition As Boolean
pageNumber = 1
printCondition = False

'Drucke Seite 1
For productNumber = 10 To 61
    ActiveSheet.Cells(productNumber, "C").Select
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(productNumber, "C").Value <> "" Then
    printCondition = True
    End If
Next

If printCondition = True Then
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End If
printCondition = False
pageNumber = pageNumber + 1


'Drucken der restlichen Seiten
For Each HPB In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
    breakAdress = CInt(Mid(HPB.Location.Address, 4, 5))


    'Teste, ob Lieferschein Einträge enthält
     For productNumber = (breakAdress + 9) To (breakAdress + 60)
           If ActiveSheet.Cells(productNumber, "C").Value <> "" Then
                printCondition = True
           End If
     Next

    If printCondition = True Then
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=pageNumber, To:=pageNumber, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    End If

    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    printCondition = False

Next
End Sub
```

But this macro sent a printjob for each page. How can i print the relevant pages  by sending only one printjob?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do this for sheets, but not the pages as far as I know since there is no property from printout that handles an array of pages, instead of a sequence. One trick would be moving your pages to sheets and then try to print selected sheets that you have saved their names in an array: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(PrintCollection).PrintOut` where PrintCollection is an array of sheets

Comment: Yes, I found several ways for print collections of sheets.

The copy solution seems to be very annoyng, but I'm going to try this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code would to be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim hp As HPageBreak
    Dim vAddress()
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    n = Ws.HPageBreaks.Count

    For i = 0 To n
        ReDim Preserve vAddress(i)
        If i = 0 Then
        vAddress(i) = Ws.Range("a1").Address
        Else
        vAddress(i) = Ws.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Address
        End If
            Set rngDB = Ws.Range(vAddress(i)).Range("c5").Resize(21) 'Range("c5").Resize (21) is coumn C date range
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngDB) Then
                Ws.PrintOut from:=i + 1, To:=i + 1, preview:=True
            End If
    Next i

End Sub
```